# How can i refactor my angular code for my laravel app so i have the controllers in separate files?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I would like to have the code as structured as possible and right now all my controllers and routes are kept in the same file. I am using laravel 4.2 for the back end and templating and angular for the front end part of the app.

This is how the angular script looks like now:

```
var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', ['ngRoute', 'ui.select', 'ngSanitize'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

Application.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/packing/scan.html', {
            templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
            controller: 'PackingScanController'
        })

        [ .... ]

});

Application.controller('BootstrapController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    [ ... ]

}]);


Application.controller('OrdersTrackerController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    [ ... ]

}]);
```

in Bootstrap.blade.php i have the base of the app and i use a n angular view to generate the content. i tried to use blade to include the needed js file containing the module's controller but that breaks angular

like this :

Scan.blade.php

```
@head
{{ HTML::script('/src/Packing/Scan.js') }}
@stop

php and angular html code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extra module, like:

```
angular.module('ReporterApp.Controllers', [ /* dependencies here */])
```

Then you can do .controller( ...etc...). Then inject this module in your 'main' module. That way you can have different files containing different controllers, all in the ReporterApp.Controllers module.

A simple example:

File 1:

```
angular.module('ReporterApp.Controllers')
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       /* code here */
    }]);
```

File 2:

```
angular.module('ReporterApp.Controllers')
    .controller('mySecondCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         /* code here */
    }]);
```

Then a module file (for the extra bit of structure, for example if you have other files with services which you want in a separate module aswell) modules.js:

```
angular.module('ReporterApp.Controllers', [ /*dependencies here */ ]);
angular.module('ReporterApp.Services', [ /* dependencies here */]);
```

And lastly your main app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('ReporterApplication', 
    ['ReporterApp.Controllers', 'ReporterApp.Services']);
```

In order for this to work properly, the order of including matters a lot though. Make sure you include the module.js file first, so that the modules are created, then the files containing the controllers, then the services and lastly your app.js!